# how to upload large video on databaes and fetch on page using php my sql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

The code below is used for uploading video files to a MySQL database or copying them to folders. In this code small videos are uploaded but large files do not work. I am using phpmysql. What do I miss?

```
 <?
 ob_start();
  ?>

  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload !">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?
include('connection.php');
{
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $name= $_FILES['file']['name'];
     $temp= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $tp= $_FILES['file']['type'];

    move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);

   $url = "";

  $insert = mysql_query
    ("INSERT INTO 'videos' VALUE ('','$name','$url')");

  if ($insert)
 {
    echo "has been uploaded";
}
}
 }
?>
```

Comment: what is the error when you trying to upload a big file?

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem you are facing.

Comment: Error is
Warning: POST Content-Length of 26246317 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the following values in your `php.ini`

```
max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 600
memory_limit = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1512M
post_max_size = 2048M
```

(You have to change the values accordingly to your needs)

Answer (score 0):

Go into your php.ini setting and change

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = #number

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = #number
```

If you haven't changed it, then it is preventing big file sizes. I did the same with huge megapixel images and found the cause to be that.

To prevent it from being an issue, set it to **0**.

Comment: i am change in php.ini but again give me error
 POST Content-Length of 26246317 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Did you set both of those to 0?

Comment: POST Content-Length of 48825015 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

 
i am change in php.ini but again give me error

Comment: hii  Mitch Mullvain
error is fix 
but data not insert into database

Comment: If the error is fixed then, it is a mysql problem. Most likely, the sql string isn't perfect. It is very picky on syntax and logic, so double check. If it uploads to your directory, but not the database, it is an sql problem.

Comment: SELECT first_name + ' ' + last_name AS emp_name FROM employee; this query not run out put is o